# What resources are available for learning Dynare?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, computation, dynare

What resources are available for learning Dynare? I think it'd be nice to put together a list of resources that available to those new to Dynare. I've had a little experience with it but it'd be nice to know what resources I might be able to go to for questions on the beginner/intermediate level. Also, I would prioritize resources that have full-fledged examples. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: In addition to official docs, I'd suggest [Practicing Dynare](https://files.nyu.edu/ts43/public/research/AP_tom16.pdf) for several examples, and J. Pfeifer's [advice](https://bbcb79fe-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/pfeiferecon/Pfeifer_2013_Observation_Equations.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cp7DvRD8kcVqyJnYHHnH-TA45WbFfjsGr2D_l9pYk-L8gDM_edaeJfxaolPPQVTomIL01rk1x923UqGC6DvxaYoYaIpe_o6C_66n3T_Tv-RRuqZR31n7adsO9qke3KKa5JZdTt5dThfLEpWrpL1bi9VzY2Ebd6TeP6zCqi7UDfdtMzhtOXzpQPhc8f5bN1FruRPAEAwXBP9gsSEdP2ReYXNdSdbmUFCZjl6Xt8fDQPBTozCcyKO1u5yPJPGtGNSUAIWFsT8&attredirects=0) for estimation.

Comment: Although not dealing with Dynare specifically Harald Uhligs "A Toolkit for Analyzing Nonlinear Dynamic Stochastic Models Easily" is an excellent reference when dealing with DSGE models and log-linearization:
http://www.sfu.ca/~kkasa/uhlig1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Eric Sims at Notre Dame has an excellent set of [self contained notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~esims1/using_dynare_sp15.pdf).

He uses a small neoclassical model as an example and goes over the model derivation, how to construct each block of Dynare code, different simulation options, interpreting output, and how to do higher order approximations. Full code is included for each step in the notes.

Comment: This community thanks you for the link. Nevertheless, this answer would be great if you could add a little something about what these notes contain, what models do they work out as examples... things like that.

Comment: I have gone over these notes, but are there codes available for his medium sized dsge model? that would come closer to what we actually try and do in research

Answer (score 1):

- [Here](http://www.dynare.org/news/macroeconomic-model-database) is a collection of 38 models implemented in Dynare. As the page states:

  > It includes small, medium- and large-scale models of the United States, the Euro Area, Canada, and several small , medium- and large-scale models of the United States, the Euro Area, Canada, and several small open emerging economies. In addition, there are a few models with two or more economies.
  >
  > The list includes state-of-the art DSGE models, earlier-generation New-Keynesian models with rational expectations as well as more traditional Keynesian-style models with adaptive expectations. [...]
  >
  > Recent applications involve economic forecasting, monetary policy optimization under model uncertainty, evaluation of fiscal stimulus and the effects of the zero bound on nominal interest rates.
- [Here](https://github.com/JohannesPfeifer/DSGE_mod) is another collection of 40 models. They include replication of several well-known papers, implementation of models from [Gali's books](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/10495.html), and other standard models like RBC and Solow.